# how to download android docs in android studio 4.1.3

Tags: android, api, documentation

As we know, in andoird studio older version, we can download documentation for android api by sdk manager tool. But sdk manager tool do not provide docs download function in android studio 4.1.3 version. We can download source code in this version. Source code is not intuitive like api docs. Now, I have to reading online docs from [developer.android.google.cn](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference) website.

Comment: I only see two ways: Download the AOS project and build it including JavaDoc or try to extract the downloaded sources into a self-created gradle project and build JavaDoc yourself.